# Using If statement to check if cell is blank, if so then do not print and move to next segment of code

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

Below I have the code that is working for me currently.  However, it is not as smart of a code as I would like.  This code filters a table then copies the results to another page to be printed.  In the end I do not want a page to print if there are no soaps to order for the particular company listed.  I keep thinking that I must use an "If" statement or maybe a Loop, but cannot quite grasp the concept in this instance.  Also, in an ideal world I would like to allow any user to come in an add another company to the list if necessary and have the code adjust to that.  While I'm not asking for that code, if someone can point me in the right direction where I could figure it out myself I would be grateful too.  Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmbPrintEchoFrance_Click()
Dim OrderForm As Worksheet
Dim PO As Worksheet
Dim SoapList As ListObject
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rngToCopy As Range, rRange As Range

Set OrderForm = Worksheets("ORDER FORM")
Set PO = Worksheets("PRINT ORDER")

Set SoapList = Worksheets("ORDER FORM").ListObjects("SOAP_LIST")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With OrderForm
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rRange = .Range("A1:A" & lRow)

'Remove any filters
.AutoFilterMode = False

    With rRange
        'print the Echo France order
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="WAVERTREE & LONDON"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
        .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
        PO.Range("E12").Value = "WAVERTREE & LONDON"
        PO.PrintOut
    End With

    With rRange
        'print the Echo France order
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="ECHO FRANCE"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
        .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
        PO.Range("E12").Value = "ECHO FRANCE"
        PO.PrintOut
    End With

    'clear print order
    PO.Range("D14:F84").Clear
    PO.Range("D14:F84").ClearFormats

    With rRange
        'print the european soaps order
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="EUROPEAN SOAPS"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
        .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
        PO.Range("E12").Value = "EUROPEAN SOAPS"
        PO.PrintOut
    End With

    'clear print order
    PO.Range("D14:F84").Clear
    PO.Range("D14:F84").ClearFormats

    With rRange
        'print the la lavande order
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="LA LAVANDE"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("D14")
        .Range("B1:B" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("E14")
        .Range("D1:D" & lRow).Copy PO.Range("F14")
        PO.Range("E12").Value = "LA LAVANDE"
        PO.PrintOut
    End With

     'clear print order
    PO.Range("D14:F84").Clear
    PO.Range("D14:F84").ClearFormats

End With
SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
SoapList.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to have a block ("print the Echo France order") repeated there - is that intentional?

Comment: Sometimes you're working with `SoapList` and sometimes with `rRange` - do those represent the same sets of data?

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh, no that was not meant to be there.  I was in the middle of adding another company.  Also, I can remove the rRange since I never seemed to use it.  SoapList is the most important range in this whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: refactored a little so you can pass in a company name and it will print the PO for that company.  The Sub "Tester" shows an example of how you would call it.

```
'print a couple of orders
Sub Tester()

    PrintCompanyPO "ECHO FRANCE" 'has items: will print
    PrintCompanyPO "xxx"         'has no items: will not print anything

End Sub


'print the order for the supplied "company" value
Private Sub PrintCompanyPO(company As String)

Dim OrderForm As Worksheet
Dim PO As Worksheet
Dim SoapList As ListObject
Dim bHaveRows As Boolean
Dim rngData As Range

    Set OrderForm = Worksheets("ORDER FORM")
    Set PO = Worksheets("PRINT ORDER")

    Set SoapList = OrderForm.ListObjects("SOAP_LIST")
    Set rngData = SoapList.DataBodyRange 'represents the actual data in your list

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'apply filter
    With SoapList.Range
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=company
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

        'test to see whether any rows are still visible
        bHaveRows = AnyVisibleCells(rngData)

        If bHaveRows Then
            .Columns(1).Copy PO.Range("D14")
            .Columns(2).Copy PO.Range("E14")
            .Columns(4).Copy PO.Range("F14")
            PO.Range("E12").Value = company
            PO.PrintOut
            With PO.Range("D14:F84")
                .Clear
                .ClearFormats
            End With
        End If

        'clear filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1
        .AutoFilter Field:=3
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Function to see if there are any non-hidden cells in a range
Function AnyVisibleCells(rng As Range)
Dim r As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore any error
    Set r = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    AnyVisibleCells = Not r Is Nothing
End Function
```